# wordpress custom rewrite rule

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get a custom rewrite rule to work, but at the moment it doesn't work. maybe someone can help?

speaking url I want looks like this: `domain/the-brand/xyz`

`domain/?pagename=brand-2&brand=xyz` is the working url...

i added already a custom tag to functions.php :

```
function custom_rewrite_tag() {
  add_rewrite_tag('%brand%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);
```

and a custom rule, but there seems to be an error:

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('/the-brand/([^/]*)' , 'index.php?pagename=brand-2&brand=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

Comment: "There seems to be an error." -- And what error is this, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're doing the right thing, you'll just want to refresh your permalinks [as noted here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API)

> Note that these rules are usually called inside the init hook.
>   Furthermore, permalinks will need to be refreshed (you can do this
>   from your admin under Settings > Permalinks) before the rewrite
>   changes will take effect. Requires one-time use of flush_rules() to
>   take effect. See also Flushing Rewrite on Activation.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

add_rewrite_rule('^the-brand/([^/]*)/?' , 'index.php?pagename=brand-2&brand=$matches[1]', 'top');